# using xml files to create objects in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

EDIT: I am editing this question because it is my only down-voted question and I am trying to get a question ban lifted.

I am currently using an xml file for a text based game. I have written the file already and I know how to read from the file, but I am confused as to how to create actual objects from the file. My question is how do I transfer from the xml file to an actual C# object. I am looking for either direct code, or a good tutorial (of which I have extensively searched and been unable to find.) Below is a samle of my xml file and my C# code as well.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<rooms>
  <room>
    <entrance>
      <Description>
        <Entry1>
        You walk up and try the door bell. No answer...You force your way into the large, heavy, oak door. In the main foyer, you take
        a quick look around. You see a baseball bat by the door and a Super Snack on a nearby dresser. Carved into one of the walls are the
        words "First is 0." There is a door to the west and a door to the north.
        </Entry1>
        <Entry2>
          You are back in the main foyer. Carved into one of the walls are the words "First is 0."   There are doors to the west, north, or east.
        </Entry2>
        <Entry3>
          You are back in the main foyer. You see a baseball bat by the door. Carved into one of the walls are the words "First is 0."
          There are doors to the west, north, and east.
        </Entry3>
        <Entry4>
          You are back in the main foyer. You see a Super Snack on a nearby dresser. Carved into one of the walls are the words "First is 0." There
          are doors to the west, north, and east.
        </Entry4>
      </Description>
      <Items>
        <Item name ="Baseball Bat" type ="weapon" attribute="player.attack + 2"></Item>
        <Item name ="Super Snack" type ="consumable" attribute ="player.health = 100"></Item>
      </Items>
      <border>
        <direction>north</direction>
        <name>room2</name>
      </border>
      <border>
        <direction>west</direction>
        <name>room3</name>
      </border>
    </entrance>
  </room>
  <room>
    <room2>
      <Description>
        <Locked>You walk forward and try the door. Locked...maybe find a key?</Locked>
        <Unlocked>
          You use the key you found on the door in front of you. It fits! In the next room you find two doors: one to the west, one to the east.
          There is a picture on the wall of the professor receiving a watch from a colleague, looks like maybe a work anniversary gift.
        </Unlocked>
      </Description>
      <border>
        <direction>west</direction>
        <name>room4</name>
      </border>
      <border>
        <direction>east</direction>
        <name>room9</name>
      </border>
    </room2>
  </room>
```

This is my Rooms file C# code. There isn't much, because I'm not really sure what I need here.

using System.Xml;
namespace FirstTextBasedGame
{
    class Rooms
    {
        string description;
        string boarder;
        public Rooms()
        {
            //unsure where to go from here...
        }
    }
}

Comment: Just to be clear, the items and rooms are two different entities you are applying the question to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML should work perfectly. A lot of game developers (talking only out of my own experience) use XML along with serialization in order to define and create these kind of entities.

You could have something like:

```
 <room id="3203jfjb" width="10" height="40">
  <items>
    <item name="table">
    </item>
    <item name="chest" type="container">
      <containerItems>
        <item name="knife">

        </item>
      </containerItems>
    </item>
  </items>
</room>
```

What is great about the approach is now you can create an serialize(able) class `Item` which you can use in both rooms and in your inventory system.

And as such easily transfer items from one object i.e `PlayerInventory` to `Room` and visa versa. You could also save the entire room state as well as your inventory to an XML file. Making saving and loading game states a lot less painful.

Somethings you might find interesting:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/443525/serialize-a-gameobject-including-components.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: One more question on this. I read through your links, and I also read about serialization. I understand how this code here works:

Comment: One more question on this. I read through your links, and I also read about serialization. I understand how the code shown here works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656717.aspx  But if you have multiple objects in a room of type Room, and you instantiate that room, do all those objects get created at the same time, or do you have to do each one individually? And how do I call a specific room out of a series of rooms?

Comment: @ethancodes Do your rooms have names? At the simplest level, use those names to differentiate between them. Or use some other identifier so you can tell one from another. Likewise the items. Are all "knife" the same, or are some sharp vs being dull. PS, at the top of Mfusiki's room, he has an id value.